# javascript React Form onsubmit save submitted username

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component with a form what I need to do is to catch the username and then save it using sessionstorage.

Here's is what I'm currently trying but it's not saving it.

Here's the code:

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      password: '',
      redirect: false,
    };

    this.onUsernameChange = this.onUsernameChange.bind(this);
    this.onPasswordChange = this.onPasswordChange.bind(this);
  }

  onUsernameChange(event) {
    this.setState({ username: event.target.value });
  }

  onPasswordChange(event) {
    this.setState({ password: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit() { 
    event.preventDefault();
    sessionStorage.setItem('username', this.username);

  }

  render() {

    return (
        <div>
          <form className="form-signin" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input type="text" value={this.username} onChange={this.onUsernameChange} />
            <input type="password" value={this.password} onChange={this.onPasswordChange} />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: You aren't passing event to `handleSubmit`.  Shouldn't it be `handleSubmit(event)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to add `username` to the state, and then pass `event` to `handleSubmit`

```
 class Login extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          password: '',
          redirect: false,
          username: ''
        };

    this.onUsernameChange = this.onUsernameChange.bind(this);
    this.onPasswordChange = this.onPasswordChange.bind(this);
  }

  onUsernameChange(event) {
    this.setState({ username: event.target.value });
  }

  onPasswordChange(event) {
    this.setState({ password: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    sessionStorage.setItem('username', this.state.username);

  }

  render() {

    return (
        <div>
          <form className="form-signin" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input type="text" value={this.username} onChange={this.onUsernameChange} />
            <input type="password" value={this.password} onChange={this.onPasswordChange} />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
handleSubmit(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    //  sessionStorage.setItem('username', this.username); your code
    sessionStorage.setItem('username', this.state.username);
  }
```

You have got username by using this.username. But there is no username in this. 
So you get username from component's state.

And your method has no arguments. If you want event you put event in argument.

Comment: but he didn't even have `username` in the initial state.

Comment: Of course. But when onUsernameChange method calls the username state is updated to state. The initial state is only for initialize your component. You can add extra states into local state by using setState method.

Comment: What happens if the user tries to submit without typing anything in the username filed?  Would that create an edgecase that we could handle with initial state?

Comment: Without typing anything the user submit the button store date as undefined. If initial state has username with empty string store data as empty string. So check username then stored it.